# My first mongo insertion (python)

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

Trying to insert my first piece of data that looks like this:

```
{
    "city": "Oakland", 
    "latitude": "37.800427", 
    "longitude": "-122.275880", 
    "state": "California", 
    "zipcode": "94607"
}
```

And when I call:

```
def establish_client(self):
    self.client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    self.db = self.client['props']

def insert_mongo(self,property_arg):
    props = self.db.props
    props.insert(property_arg) #err line
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 3.4.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 930, in doIt
    result = pydevd_vars.evaluateExpression(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, self.doExec)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 3.4.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd_vars.py", line 239, in evaluateExpression
    Exec(expression, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 3.4.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 409, in insert
    gen(), check_keys, self.uuid_subtype, client)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 386, in gen
    doc['_id'] = ObjectId()
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

What gives?

My object that i am inserting is generated by the following function embedded in the class itself:

```
def to_JSON(self):
    return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__,
        sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to dump the dictionary into JSON string, just pass the dictionary itself to `insert()`.

Quote from the [tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#documents) that should clear things up:

> Data in MongoDB is represented (and stored) using JSON-style
>   documents. **In PyMongo we use dictionaries to represent documents.**

Comment: the reason I converted to a dictionary is that the data being inserted in an object. Should I insert the object directly?

Comment: @jasonm you haven't provided the complete class definition, but it looks like you need to use `self.__dict__` directly or filter it's relevant part that you need to persist.

Comment: thanks for making me aware of `self.__dict__` this is incredibly useful. absolutely what i needed!